# How can I change my React class to a function so that I can include Material UI classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, material-ui, webstorm

After finally managing to set up Emailjs, I am now trying to use Material UI text fields (https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#text-field) for a better design.

Unfortunately I cannot manage to add Material UI classes to my code, since I a, not able to change the Class to a Functional Component with a state. Does anyone know how I can change the class to a function so that I can use Material UI designs for my Contact Form?

My EmailJS form (works perfectly fine , only changed my user and template ID before posting it here):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as emailjs from 'emailjs-com'
import { Button, FormFeedback, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap'


class ContactForm extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        message: '',
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { name, email, subject, message } = this.state
        let templateParams = {
            from_name: email,
            to_name: 'Altes Waschhaus',
            subject: subject,
            message_html: message,
        }
        emailjs.send(
            'gmail',
            'template_XXXXX',
            templateParams,
            'user_XXXXX'
        )
        this.resetForm()
    }
    resetForm() {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: '',
        })
    }
    handleChange = (param, e) => {
        this.setState({ [param]: e.target.value })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                    <h1 className="p-heading1">Get in Touch</h1>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Label className="text-muted">Email address</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                className="text-primary"
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')}
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicName">
                            <Label className="text-muted">Name</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                                value={this.state.name}
                                className="text-primary"
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
                                placeholder="Name"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicSubject">
                            <Label className="text-muted">Subject</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="text"
                                name="subject"
                                className="text-primary"
                                value={this.state.subject}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'subject')}
                                placeholder="Subject"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicMessage">
                            <Label className="text-muted">Message</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="textarea"
                                name="message"
                                className="text-primary"
                                value={this.state.message}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'message')}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" value="Send">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default ContactForm
```

Comment: You want to convert this class component into functional component and also you want to use state, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That is my problem! Will add that point to the description +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use only functional based components to use material ui.

You can still use class based components and make use of [withStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) to use the classes.

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    //etc...
  },
};



class ContactForm extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        subject: '',
        message: '',
    }
    ...
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props; //<----- grab classes here in the props
        return (
            <>
                    <h1 className="p-heading1">Get in Touch</h1>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <FormGroup controlId="formBasicEmail">
                            <Label className="text-muted">Email address</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                className="text-primary"
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')}
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                        ....
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(ContactForm) //<----- see here
```

Comment: Thank you, that already helps a bit, the design of the button changed +1
The problem I am now facing now is that if I also want to import and use the TextFields from Material UI (so if I change Formgroup to TextField) then I dont receive the content via EmailJs. Is there a way to include the <TextField> or <DatePicker> Material UI functions into the Formgroup?

Comment: you can also use material ui's [FormGroup](https://material-ui.com/api/form-group/) .... it is better to not mix up multiple ui libraries unless you really need to ... if you still need to use multiple ui libraries, can you put ur code in a sandbox and share the link .. i can have a look and make it work..

Comment: Thank you, that would be so great.


This is basically my back-end:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hugle-ju6uv?file=/src/ContactForm.js

And this my front-end:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hugle-ju6uv?file=/src/Kontakt.js

I would be enough if you show me how to do it on one or two boxes. That would be a big help already!

Comment: the two files in the sandbox were duplicates. I changed that now,